# Solve initial value problem with unspecified right-hand side $g(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

Consider the initial value problem 
$$y''-6y'+9y=g(t),\quad y(0)=1,\ y'(0)=3.$$

1) Use the Convolution Theorem to find the solution to the IVP **for any piecewise continuous function $g(t)$ that is of exponential order.**

2) Using the solution from above, what is the solution of $g(t)=e^{3t}$?

Transform:

$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)-6[sY(s)-y(0)]+9Y(s)=G(s)$

$s^2Y(s)-s-3-6sY(s)+6+9Y(s)=G(s)$

$(s^2-6s+9)Y(s)=s+3+G(s)$

$Y(s)=\frac{s+3}{s^2-6s+9}+\frac{G(s)}{s^2-6s+9} $

I am stuck here. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a $-s-3+6=-s+3$ on the *left-hand side*, so when it goes to the right-hand side, you get 
$$
Y(s)=\frac{\color{blue}{s-3}}{s^2-6s+9}+\frac{G(s)}{s^2-6s+9}.
$$
Then, since $s^2-6s+9=(s-3)^2$,
\begin{align}
Y(s)&=\frac{s-3}{s^2-6s+9}+\frac{G(s)}{s^2-6s+9}\\
&=\frac{s-3}{(s-3)^2}+\frac{G(s)}{(s-3)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{s-3}+\frac{G(s)}{(s-3)^2}.\\
\end{align}
Take the inverse Laplace transform of each piece, using the Convolution Theorem on the last term:
\begin{align}
y(t)&=e^{3t}+\mathscr{L^{-1}}\left\{G(s)\cdot\frac{1}{(s-3)^2}\right\}\\
&=e^{3t}+g(t)*te^{3t}\\
&=e^{3t}+\int_0^t g(t-s)se^{3s}\,ds.
\end{align}

When $g(t)=e^{3t}$ (which is what I *suspect* you meant), this becomes
\begin{align}
y(t)&=e^{3t}+\int_0^t g(t-s)se^{3s}\,ds\\
&=e^{3t}+\int_0^t e^{3(t-s)}se^{3s}\,ds\\
&=e^{3t}+\int_0^t e^{3t}e^{-3s}se^{3s}\,ds\\
&=e^{3t}+e^{3t}\int_0^t s\,ds\\
&=e^{3t}+{1\over 2}t^2e^{3t}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now i see where i made the mistake

Comment: I dont have the permissions to upvote yet. I tried that before and that's why i left a comment for you

Comment: OK, didn't know. I upvoted you so you would gain points. Hopefully others will do the same.